# Google map not getting displayed even after providing API Key

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Im trying to display google map on my website. Here is the code:-

```
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapz'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Here is the error displayed in the console:-
message:"initMap is not a function"
name:"InvalidValueError"

Comment: This script must be included into html BEFORE your Google maps api script

Comment: @MysterX the error has gone from console but map has not yet displayed

Comment: check also if you have html element with id `mapz` and it must have predefined width and height

Comment: give proper height and width to `mapz` container, map sometimes doesn't show when element doesn't have height and width

Comment: height and width are defined for id mapz but google map is not displayed

Comment: Pleae provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip if you have noticed i have used the code from google itself. since whatt im trying to achieve in my site is quite elaborative. after running the above code im getting same error. so i believe what i provided above is a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Here is the link:-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: Help us to help you.  Google's example works.  You claim yours doesn't.  Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. What HTML/CSS are you using? How are you calling the `initMap` function?

Comment: And help me to understand yu .. pls dont ask the same thing which we dont understand "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"
There are people like me out there hu dosent understand wht yu are saying so please try to help us understand.
the initMap is called using 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="MYAPIKEY"&callback=initMap"></script>
PS:Key cannot be reveled

Comment: @Jackson - one of two possibilities. 1) You are overriding the global variable `initMap` somewhere else with something that is not a function or 2) The code snippet that you are showing in your question is **not actually on the page you are loading** (happens more often than you think). The error you are seeing is the google maps API trying to call `initMap()` - the 
parameter you passed it `&callback=initMap` when you embedded the maps api JS on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Below code. Hope It helps you..!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&sensor=false">
<div id="mapz" style="width: 80%; height: 500px"></div>
<script>
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapz'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```